# Links or materials to learn more about IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am interested to learn more about IBM Worklight, so can anyone help me in sharing the links or materials that could be found in sites other than documents found in this link: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

Comment: if your question is answered - please mark as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IBM Worklight homepage:**

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/index.html

**IBM Worklight whitepapers and more:**

- http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/worklight
  http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/worklight#show-hide
  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/learn.html

**IBM Worklight Getting Started:**

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

**IBM Worklight Information Center:**

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp

**IBM Worklight blog:**

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/worklight/?lang=en

**IBM Worklight in YouTube:**

- http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ibm+worklight&oq=ibm+worklight&gs_l=youtube.3..35i39l2j0l3.236.1204.0.1675.13.11.0.0.0.0.214.1432.3j7j1.11.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.JhpF47bNhHQ

**Google:**

- https://www.google.com/#gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=yLKaMC9-HDMkOcE6f5-7pQ&cp=6&gs_id=m&xhr=t&q=ibm+worklight

Comment: I would also recommend phonegap/cordova docs for creating plugins:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html (choose whatever version based on your WL install)